# Need to find elements by title

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to find an element that has a particular title. The only problem is that the title contains spaces.

e.g. title "Customer Center And Services"

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the title selector

```
$("[title='Customer Center And Services']")
```

And for further reading refer to http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I tried that. For some strange reasons it dint seem to work. Let me give it another try. Thanks

Comment: It worked. Seems there was some issue with the code I was testing with.Thanks